# Is this situation haram?

Tags: shaitan, halal-haram

So one day I was just joking around with my siblings and my sister and my sister said a joke about me and after that I said “your worse than shaitan”. Keep in mind I didn’t mean this sentence I know no one is worse the shaitan it was just a joke I said. So is this considered haram? Even if it was a joke.

Answer (score -1):

I don’t think that it is haram, only major sins that have bad consequences and habits are considered haram. There is also intention and I think you don’t have any bad intention as you were only joking, so ask for taubah and don’t worry that is is haram.